# I miss response .status when HTTP response status 400,

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-codes

my problem is when i use custom axios aka axiosInstance, i only catch res.status == 200, when response is status 400, i can not take res.status and use it.
My config custom axios:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { API_AUTH } from "./urlConfig";
import store from "../store";
import { authConstants } from "../store/actions/constants";

const token = localStorage.getItem("token") ? localStorage.getItem("token") : sessionStorage.getItem("token");

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_AUTH,
    headers: {
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => {
        return res;
    },
    (err) => {
        const { status } = err.response;
        if (status === 400) {
            localStorage.clear();
            store.dispatch({ type: authConstants.LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
        }
        return err;
    }
);
export default axiosInstance;
```

and this code when i use axios

```
import { authConstants } from "./constants";
import { LOGIN } from "../../helpers/urlConfig";
import authAPI from "../../helpers/authAPI";

export const login = (input) => {
    const { isRemember, ...inputUser } = input;

    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: authConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST,
        });

        const res = await authAPI.post(LOGIN, {
            ...inputUser,
        });

        if (res.status === 200) {
            //do something OK when status code = 200.
        }
        if (res.status === 400) {
            //can not take res and check res.status
            console.log("res", res);            
        }
    };
};
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to handle the error using `catch`.

Usually I am doing something like this:

```
const res = await authAPI.post(LOGIN, { 
   ...inputUser
}).catch(error => ({
    status: error.response.status,
    data: error.response.data
}))
```

then you should be able to get `res.status` properly.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, it works fine. Good job bro.